# Tcl script can't read "startreg(1)": no such variable

Tags: geometry, tcl

I tried to run a Tcl script that creates a geometry file from an input file (where the geometry is defined). The script can be run simply as script.tcl inputfile. 
When I run it (on both Mac and Linux) using either wish or tclsh command, I get this error:

```
        can't read "startreg(1)": no such variable
        while executing
    "if { $startreg($i)==0 && $stopreg($i)==0 } {
            # All are material 1, change nothing
            } else {
            for {set iz $startz($i)} {$iz<=$stopz($i)} {incr i..."
        invoked from within
    "if [string compare $descrip regions]==0 {
        # Get the mednum, start and stop regions
        seek $fileid $startpos start
        while { [eof $fileid] != 1 } {
           ..."
        (procedure "read_inputfile" line 214)
        invoked from within
    "read_inputfile "
        invoked from within
    "if [file exists $inputfile]==1 {
        read_inputfile 
    } else {
        puts "The file $inputfile doesn't exist!"
        exit
    }"
        (file "~/EGS_Windows/preview3d.tcl" line 580)
```

Any help/suggestion would be highly appreciated!
TA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You apparently have never initialized that variable.

```
% array set startreg {}
% puts $startreg(1)
can't read "startreg(1)": no such element in array
% unset startreg
% puts $startreg(1)
can't read "startreg(1)": no such variable
```

Is `startreg` a global variable, and you forgot to `global startreg` in a proc?

---

I notice another error in the stacktrace

```
if [string compare $descrip regions]==0 {
```

You surely want braces around the condition, so that the test is performed when you expect it to be performed:

```
if {[string compare $descrip regions]==0} {
```

This applies to all `if` expressions, and all `expr`essions in general. See this wiki page: http://wiki.tcl.tk/10225

In this case, `if {$descrip eq "regions"}` is more clear.

Comment: Thanks @glennjackman for your reply, I am not familiar with Tcl scripts, it is my first time.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend going through the [Tcl tutorial](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/tcltutorial.html)

Comment: Thanks @glennjackman, I downloaded that script and I thought it was ready to go without any modification.

Comment: I found this line in the script: global inputfile fileid radii depth zff medium startreg stopreg mednum, so the writer did not forget to global startreg. What should I do ? About the if expression, I found some lines are the same as you mentioned and some as it is shown above. @glennjackman

Comment: Don't know. Have to see the code. Is that `global` statement in *every* proc that uses those variables? In particular here, the `read_inputfile` proc.